# Extract and group data in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping

I have a CSV dataset which I've imported using Pandas read_csv function, and when I run .head() I get the following table output:

```
    LSOA code             Crime type
0   E01006687               Burglary
1   E01007229  Anti-social behaviour
2   E01007229  Anti-social behaviour
3   E01007229  Anti-social behaviour
4   E01007229               Burglary
5   E01007229            Other theft
6   E01007229            Other theft
7   E01007229            Shoplifting
8   E01007229  Theft from the person
9   E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
10  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
11  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
12  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
13  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
14  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
15  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
16  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
17  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
18  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
19  E01007230  Anti-social behaviour
```

This table has over 33,000 rows. What I need to do is to get all the unique  values of 'LSOA code' - of which there are 207, and then for each 'LSOA code', I need a value for the number of occurances of each 'Crime type' .. of which there are about 30, and then a sum of the total crimes for each LSOA code

Eg: I'd like the following sort of output table, where 'LSOA code' is the index column:

```
LSOA code | Burglary | Anti-social Behavior | Bicycle Theft | Assault ... | Total

E01000067 | 32 | 21 | 8 | 43 ... | 1023

E01000043 | 98 | 65 | 5 | 73 ... | 2308

E01000237 | 38 | 34 | 12 | 92 ... | 897

E01000038 | 82 | 28 | 3 | 18 ... | 2147
```

etc.

I've managed to get the LSOA codes into a dataframe, with the total number of crimes in each LSOA using the following:

```
WirralCrimes = Crimes['LSOA code'].value_counts()
CrimeDF = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(WirralCrimes))
CrimeDF.columns = ["Count"]
```

..but I can't work out how to get each crime type in a column and sum up the occurances for each LSOA

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to what I should do?

Many thanks

Comment: Note that posting an image of a dataframe instead of the text version is much less useful, because no one can copy and paste it to reproduce the frame.  If someone wanted to show how an approach worked on your data, they'd have to type the whole thing manually.

Comment: Hey, sorry but I don't get how to include the text? The table output is a HTML table as I'm using Jupyter. Is there a way for me to include the actual text?

Comment: maybe something like `print(df.head().to_string())`?

Comment: Ahh excellent. Please see the edit containing the new table (with redundant columns omitted) in string form

Answer (score 0):

This should work now if the data you have resembles this:

```
df = DataFrame({'LSOA code':['E01006687','E01007229','E01007229','E01007229','E01007229','E01007229','E01007229','E01007229','E01007230','E01007230']
, 'Crime type':['Burglary','Anti-social behaviour','Anti-social behaviour','Anti-social behaviour','Burglary','Other theft','Other theft','Shoplifting','Theft from the person','Anti-social behaviour']})


your_data['count'] = 1

table = pandas.pivot_table(your_data, index='LSOA code', columns='Crime type',values='count',aggfunc='sum')
table ["total"] = table.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: Hi- thanks for your comment. Your solution sort of worked, but the extra columns in the dataframe messed things up a bit, so I dropped everything that was not needed (see my edited question) and now it outputs the error:

    DataError: No numeric types to aggregate